# Set query string in aspx code behind file?

Tags: asp.net

I know how to read a query string:

```
Request.QueryString["value"];
```

But how do I set a query string in my page_load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx?q=yourquerystringparameter");
```

Comment: Doh, why didn't I think of that >_<